# General definition of characteristic function of a random variable and characteristic function of a probability measure

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

Let $(\mu_n)_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $(\hat{\mu}_n){_n\geq1}$ denote their Fourier transforms (aka characteristic functions).
 Starting from the definition of characteristic function of a random variable $X$ (defined on a probability space $(\Omega\text{, }\mathcal{F}\text{, }\mu)$) as $$\varphi_X(u)=\hat{X}(u)=\mathbb{E}(e^{iuX})=\displaystyle\int e^{iux}d\mu(x)=\displaystyle\int e^{iux}\mu(dx)\tag{1}$$ one has that $$\hat{\mu}(u)=\displaystyle\int e^{iux}\mu(dx)\tag{2}$$

**Two questions**:

1. *As to the general definition of characteristic function of a random variable* (see $(1)$), why does it hold that $$\displaystyle\int e^{iux}d\mu(x)=\displaystyle\int e^{iux}\mu(dx)$$? 
    That is, how is it possible to show that $$d\mu(x)=\mu(dx)$$?
2. *As to the definition of the characteristic function of a probability measure* (see $(2)$), as far as I understand I am integrating a function $f(x)$ with respect to probability measure $\mu$, with $x$ representing all the possible values of $\mu$. In other terms, I am integrating the function $e^{iux}$ with respect to the probability measure $\mu$ on the domain of the probability measure $\mu$ itself. 
   Is that correct? Sorry if it could seem a bit messy.

Comment: $d\mu(x)$ and $\mu (dx)$ are two notations for one and the same thing.

Comment: So, $d\mu(x)=\mu(dx)$ is just a matter a notation and NOT a consequence of a Theorem/result? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: @Strictly_increasing Indeed just a matter of notation and not a consequence of anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int f(x)d\mu(x)$ and $\int f(x)\mu(dx)$ both denote the integral of function $f$ wrt probability measure $\mu$.

Using a more neutral notation that avoids the bound variable $x$ we could say that: $$\int f(x)d\mu(x)=\int fd\mu=\int f(x)\mu(dx)$$

For any fixed $u\in\mathbb R$ we have the (nice) function $f_u:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$ that is prescribed by: $$x\mapsto e^{iux}$$Then:$$\hat{\mu}(u):=\int f_ud\mu$$is well defined for every probability measure $\mu$ on measurable space $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$.

If $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is some random variable then it has a distribution $\mu$ on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$ prescribed by $B\mapsto P(X\in B)$.

In that situation the function $\hat{\mu}(u)$ is labeled as "characteristic function of $X$".

This all remains valid if we work in $\mathbb R^d$ and with random vectors.

Comment: My doubt arose since on my textbook it is said that $\hat{\mu}(u)$ is the "characteristic function (Fourier transform) of the probability measure $\mu$", NOT that $\hat{\mu}(u)$ is the "characteristic function (Fourier transform) of the r.v. $X$". Are these two statements indeed equivalent? Why? @drhab

Comment: @Strictly_increasing Given a random variable $X$, we have the induced measure $\mathbb{P}_X$. The characteristic function of $X$ is by definition $\hat{\mathbb{P}}_X(u)$

Comment: The statement that $\hat{\mu}(u)$ is the characteristic function of probability measure $\mu$ is more basic. It connects the function with a probability measure on $(\mathbb R^d,\mathcal B)$, and we can already speak of probability measures without speaking of random variables. But in practice often probability measures on $(\mathbb R^d,\mathcal B)$ are *induced* by random variables. In that case one also uses the terminology "characteristic function of r.v. $X$". Observe that the correspondence between Fourier transform and probability measure is one-to-one.

Comment: ...This is not so for random variables because we can have rv's $X,Y$ with $X\neq Y$ but still $P_X=P_Y$ and consequently $\hat{P_X}=\hat{P_Y}$.

Comment: Thank you a lot to both of you :)

Comment: In return thank you for editing.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, 
$$\int_X f(x) \mu(dx) = \int_X f(x) d\mu(x) = \int_X f d \mu$$

are all the same thing: a Lebesgue-integral w.r.t. the measure $\mu$.

Some authors even write things like

$$\int_X \mu(dx) f(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

There is a theorem (sometimes known as the change of variables formula) that says that, given a random vector $\mathbf{X}:(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and a measurable map $g:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R^n}$ then

> $E(g(\mathbf{X}))=\int_{\Omega}g(\mathbf{X})\text{ d}P=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g\text{ d}(P\circ \mathbf{X}^{-1})$.

So, in particular $\varphi_\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{t})=E(e^{i\mathbf{t}^\top\mathbf{X}})=\int_{\Omega}e^{i\mathbf{t}^\top\mathbf{X}}\text{ d}P=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{i\mathbf{t}^\top\mathbf{x}}\text{ d}(P\circ\mathbf{X}^{-1})$.

Obviously, $P\circ\mathbf{X}^{-1}$ is the measure over $\mathbb{R}^n$ induced by the random vector $\mathbf{X}$. You can find a proof of the change of variables formula in the theorem 1.6.9 of [Rick Durrett's book](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf).